# Function returns all values as null, even though they are not

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

This function is supposed to get information from my database table, add them to an array and display them to me (I'm using Postman for testing right now)

However, instead of returning normal values, all of them are set to null for an unknown reason, at least to me.

DbOperations.php

```
function getPersonChanges_made($login_token){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, login_token, time_started, time_ended, todays_worktime FROM changes_made WHERE login_token = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $login_token);
    $stmt->execute();
    $arrs = array(); 

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $arr  = array();
        $arr['id'] = $row['id'];
        $arr['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $arr['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
        $arr['login_token'] = $row['login_token'];
        $arr['time_started'] = $row['time_started'];
        $arr['time_ended'] = $row['time_ended'];
        $arr['todays_worktime'] = $row['todays_worktime'];

        array_push($arrs, $arr);
    }

    return $arrs;  
}
```

Api.php

```
case 'getpersonchanges_made':
    isTheseParametersAvailable(array('login_token'));
    $db = new DbOperation();
    $result = $db->getPersonChanges_made($_POST['login_token']);

    if($result){
        $response['error'] = false; 
        $response['message'] = 'success';
        $response['arrs'] = $result;
    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = 'Some error occurred please try again';
    }
    break;
```

Here is the result I get:

> "id":null,"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"login_token":null,"time_started":null,"time_ended":null,"todays_worktime":null

Comment: This is possibly not the route of your problem (it might be though), but instead of $response['arrs'] = $db->getPersonChanges_made($_POST['login_token']);   ->  Simply use: -> $response['arrs'] = $result;   .... So you don't do the whole operation twice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however the problem persists

Comment: Update the question with your amended code.

Comment: Are you sure the row has values? Try `var_dump($row);` inside of your loop to see what it contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns a boolean. You are probably looking for [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), but it can't be called on the statement directly, it can only be called on the result object. For example:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

There is another option available, which might be even simpler.

```
foreach($stmt->get_result() as $row) {
```

**Update**
As @NigelRen says you could also return the result of [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) directly, because all you do in the loop is move from one array to another without changing anything. Your function would become much cleaner and shorter:

```
function getPersonChanges_made($login_token) {
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, login_token, time_started, time_ended, todays_worktime FROM changes_made WHERE login_token = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $login_token);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(\MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: You could also add using [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) as it saves having to loop.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks I added your suggestion to the answer